# Popup com AJAX e jQuery

Tags: jquery

Preciso abrir um *popup* com as informações do meu banco de dados, quando clicar em um certo item em um *grid* que estou exibindo na tela. Como faço para exibir esse *popup*?

Comment: Já experimentas te fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar alguma biblioteca para gerar o modal? Você quer dicas de quais ferramentas pode usar ou já tem algo pronto e está com dificuldades de dar seguimento?

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho só o grid com as informações que preciso exibir e ao clicar no item desse grid, ele abriria um popup com as informações do usuáio, porem não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer, preciso começar do zero.. Se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeço....

Comment: Aconselho a usar alguma biblioteca que faça isso. Como por exemplo o bootstrap. Assim, ele cria a pop up e basta colocares la dentro o que queres exibir

Comment: Ou se queres evitar colocar o bootstrap no teu projecto, basta fazeres uma pesquisa no google que encontras como fazer uma pop up. Aqui está a 1ª que encontrei (e que me parece ser bem funcional): http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/

Comment: Como é o HTML desse botão "aprovar"?

Answer (score 6):

Esta é a sua necessidade:

> Preciso abrir um popup com as informações do meu banco de dados, quando clicar em um certo item em uma grid que estou exibindo na tela. [...]
>
> — *SirSmart, 07 de maio de 2014*

Portanto, vou suprir *parte* dela.

Em primeiro lugar, para não recriarmos a roda, usaremos o [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) para dar vida ao nosso *modal* (ou "*pop-up*", se preferir). Para isso, faça o download dele [aqui](http://jqueryui.com/download/) com, no mínimo, o **core** e o **widget → dialog**.

Depois de baixado e instalado – basta chamarmos os arquivos `.js` necessários através da tag `<script>` no HTML da sua aplicação – nós faremos com que ao clicarmos em algo específico, um [diálogo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message) seja aberto. Veja:

> **HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="1" data-name="João da Silva" data-age="25"><a href="#">João</a></li>
        <li data-id="2" data-name="Felipe Nogueira" data-age="30"><a href="#">Felipe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="dialog"></div>
```

> **JavaScript / jQuery**

```
var $item = $('.grid ul li'),
    $dialog = $('.dialog');

$dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});

$item.on('click', function() {
    var $id = $(this).data('id'),
        $name = $(this).data('name'),
        $age = $(this).data('age');
    
    $dialog.html('Este é o ' + $name + '. Ele tem ' + $age + ' anos e é o ' + $id + 'º usuário registrado.');
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

> **Dependências:** [jquery-2.1.1.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js), [jquery-ui.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js) e [jquery-ui-git.css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css)

*Para visualizar um exemplo em tempo real, acesse o [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBvFC/).*

---

O que fizemos até então foi isso:

> Preciso abrir um popup [...] quando clicar em um certo item em uma grid que estou exibindo na tela.

Agora precisamos disso:

> [...] com as informações do meu banco de dados [...]

Para conseguir realizar tal ato, eu precisaria saber especificamente do seu banco de dados. Na verdade, mesmo que eu tivesse, não o faria por você – vou te dar a faca e o queijo.

#### Com o *modal* em mãos...

... existem várias formas de completá-lo com informações do seu usuário. Um exemplo simples que eu dei fora através dos atributos HTML `data`. O problema disso é que soa como "gambiarra" porque não é a melhor prática para executar tal ação.

Se você quiser seguir o caminho certo, eu sugiro que faça uma [requisição](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) [AJAX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) solicitando as informações de um usuário específico. Para realizar isso, você segue na lógica que escrevemos em HTML/JavaScript sobre "*clicar e abrir modal*", mas antes de rechear o pop-up com as informações dos elementos `data`, faça a requisição que desejar e responda ela com os dados do elemento em que você clicou.

Por exemplo:

```
[...]

$item.on('click', function() {
    var $id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/user/' + $id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (user) {
            $dialog.html('Este é o ' + user.name + '. Ele tem ' + user.age + ' anos e é o ' + $id + 'º usuário registrado.').dialog('open');
        }
    });
}
```

Tente enviar a resposta do seu servidor no formato [`json`](http://www.tidbits.com.br/o-que-e-json-como-e-quando-utilizar) – isso é uma boa prática que trás flexibilidade e escalabilidade.

Para concluir: o fluxo desse serviço é relativamente simples. Depois que o cliente clica em algum item da lista, você vai fazer uma requisição AJAX para alguma rota da sua aplicação. No nosso caso, estávamos a utilizar `/user/$id`. Portanto, quando é-se feita uma requisição do tipo `GET` para `localhost/user/1` (por exemplo), isso significa – não necessariamente, mas no nosso caso – que teremos um retorno do tipo JSON, o que é totalmente interoperável com a requisição AJAX que tínhamos feito anteriormente. A resposta do servidor será um vetor com as informações do usuário em questão. Você itera com esses dados e distribui eles visualmente com JavaScript. O resultado será o esperado.

Answer (score 2):

Se você já tem uma função `Aprovar()` então para correr essa função a cada click, então pode amarrar um evento assim:

```
$('button').on('click', Aprovar);
```

Dependendo de que tipo de mensagem quer exibir pode colocar esse código dentro da sua função.

alert('Mensagem via alert');

ou abrindo um dialog com o jQuery, ou ainda colocando a mensagem na página com `$('seletor').html('Mensagem via HTML');`

**Para abrir um dialog** tem de carregar o jQuery UI e ter "preparado" no HTML elementos para isso:

```
<div id="myDialog"><div id="myDialogText"></div></div>
```

Então pode mudar o texto dinamicamente com `$("#myDialogText").text('Mensagem via Modal');` e depois abrir/fechar o Modal

Para abrir o Modal pode usar `$("#myDialog").dialog('open');`
Para fechar o Modal pode usar `$("#myDialog").dialog('close');`

Para abrir a página com o Modal escondido o melhor é fazer via CSS com `display: none;`

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/b5P2s/)

Comment: Galera desculpa, mas eu preciso abrir uma modal com a mensagem e não dar um alert. Como posso fazer essa modal ?

Comment: @SirSmart, acrescentei informação sobre o Modal. Era isso que procurava? o modal deve abrir antes ou depois do AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Usando a biblioteca [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/):

HTML:

```
<button id='link'>Clique-me!</button>

<div id='div' title='Meu título'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
  $('#div').html('Meu texto').dialog();
});
```

[Veja no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CBeL/).

Answer (score 0):

Baseado na sua pergunta:

> Tenho um sistema de aprovação e preciso exibir uma mensagem para o usuário toda vez que ele clicar no botão Aprovar. Como posso fazer?

Eu parto do princípio de que você já está conseguindo fazer as aprovações. Para por fim mostrar uma mensagem – que baseado no seu código não existe nada relacionado – você deve adicionar o seguinte trecho no fragmento `success` do seu `$.ajax`, assim:

```
function Aprovar() {
   $.ajax({
   [...]
       success: function (data) {
           alert("Aprovado com sucesso!");
           $("#listaParticipante").html(data);
       },
   [...]
   });
}
```

Lembrando que, esse [`alert()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) é uma função *nativa* do JavaScript e que se você quiser algo personalizado você mesmo deve fazer, porém seguindo a mesma lógica.

Comment: Galera desculpa, mas eu preciso abrir uma modal com a mensagem e não dar um alert. Como posso fazer essa modal ?

Comment: Existem vários modais. Já te ensinei a fazer um [neste tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15028/popup-com-ajax-e-jquery/15081#15081) que aparentemente você sequer deu bola.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa retornar do servidor uma string json e dar um parse nela para se tornar uma variável objeto .

```
//JQuery
var objJson = $.parseJSON("string json");

//Javascript
var objJson = JSON.parse("string json");
```

Digamos que nesse objeto json você tenha o atributo "Mensagem" você no success da chamada ajax pode simplesmente colocar o conteúdo da mensagem dentro de alguma tag html para exibição.

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#listaParticipante").html(data);
  var objJson =  $.parseJSON(data.d);
  $("#algum-elemento").text(objJson.Mensagem);
}
```

Caso não seja uma mensagem dinâmica você pode simplesmente adicionar a mensagem no success.

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#listaParticipante").html(data);
  $("#algum-elemento").text("Mensagem estática");
}
```