# Passar parâmetros para modal bootstrap via javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um sistema que possui uma versão web, vocês conseguem visualizá-lo aqui: [All in Your Hands](http://allinyourhandsweb.com). Nele vocês perceberão que existe um carrousel para exibição de conteúdos mais acessados e neste carrousel utilizo js para abrir um modal bootstrap no caso de alguns conteúdos como músicas e vídeos. 
A função javascript que é chamada para abrir o modal é esta abaixo:

```
function recommendedContentsDialodShow(){
    $('#recommendedContentsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {    


    }).modal('show');       
}
```

O problema é que não consigo abrir o modal e exibir dados nele usando EL (ex: `${nomeMusica}` ) sem fazer um request e recarregar toda a página. Como eu poderia fazer isso sem fazer um request setando estes parâmetros no escopo request ?
Já tentei recursos como c:set  mas não funcionou...

Answer (score 2):

A solução mais inteligente, na minha opinião, é que você faça uma requisição para cada modal aberto. Mas, por que, afinal?

- Sem requisição, você terá que armazenar os dados do conteúdo que você quer explodir na própria página, o que é um desperdício de banda para aqueles que **não** vão abrir um modal específico;
- Se as informações que você quer abrir no seu modal são as mesmas que já possuem em sua página, então eis aí uma oportunidade para você repensar na sua [UX](http://www.fatdux.com/pt/What/What-is-UX), porque você está replicando dados desnecessariamente;
- Considerando, por fim, que você definitivamente queira passar para o seu modal alguma variável, esteja ciente de que isso só será possível se a sua função `recommendedContentsDialodShow()` estiver no mesmo escopo da sua página que possua `${nomeMusica}`. Por exemplo:

**index.php**:

```
<?php $nomeMusica = 'The Offspring – You're gonna go far, kid'; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('<?php echo $nomeMusica; ?>');
</script>
```

- Ou seja, você **não conseguirá** tramitar a sua variável sobre escopos diferentes – nem o JavaScript e nem o PHP sabem como fazer isso. Além disso, entenda que essa mistura de linguagens, principalmente neste formato, é ruim. O ideal é você desacoplar o máximo possível uma linguagem da outra, sem fazer uma salada de frutas em um arquivo específico. Portanto, a sua solução é, se você quer invariavelmente utilizar `$nomeMusica` no seu JavaScript, certifique-se de que a declaração da mesma esteja no mesmo nível de escopo da função que a chama. Do contrário, por sua vez, utilize uma requisição `$.ajax` – este, além de ser uma alternativa que vai resolver o seu problema, é a opção mais indicada para o seu cenário.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, seus comentários foram de grande ajuda.  Vou tentar fazer utilizando a solução via ajax, no entanto como eu posso obter as informações desejadas através do ajax? Como posso obter o retorno?  Note que estou me baseando no código abaixo:   var xmlhttp;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var params = "parametros";    xmlhttp.open("POST",serverBaseURL,true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
  xmlhttp.send(params);

Comment: Oi, @rbertani. Você pode simplificar isso usando o jQuery, biblioteca esta que você já está utilizando. Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15028/popup-com-ajax-e-jquery/15081#15081), onde eu explico como fazer uma requisição AJAX. Outra coisa, o ideal é que você disponibilize as informações que desejas no modal através do formato `.json`, como uma API. Neste modelo você vai conseguir persistir seus dados com facilidade.

Comment: Olá Guilherme,  obrigado pela dica. Porém, creio que não seja exatamente o que eu quero fazer. Assim, eu estou usando  um modal bootstrap (sei que ele usa ajax por trás), no entando eu já tenho o código do modal no corpo da página e quando eu chamo o método js a idéia é abrir o modal com as informações que preciso em campos especificos deste modal usando EL, ex ${nomeMusica}.  No caso, o trecho de código do seu link:   $dialog.html()  não funcionaria...note que eu já tenho o html do modal pronto, faltando apenas algumas informações variáveis