# Como pegar o 2 valor de um indice e mostrar?

Tags: php, javascript, html

No meu programa eu faço a pesquisa dos dados da tabela e adiciono num `array v_patr` e depois eu adiciono esse `array` na `var w_a`:

```
<html>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300">
                <?
                $w_querybusca="SELECT * FROM public.sai_cad_patr_seri WHERE 
                                sai_cad_patr_seri.fk_seq_cara_peri = '$arr_w_param[17]'";     
                $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);            
                $w_indice = 0;
                while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
                {
                    print('<option value="'.$w_registro->tx_num_patr.'">'.trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr).'</option>'."\n");

                    print("<SCRIPT language=javascript>  
                               v_patr[$w_indice] = \"$w_registro->tx_num_patr,$w_registro->tx_num_seri\";
                           w_a = v_patr[$w_indice];
                           </SCRIPT>"); 

                    $w_indice++;
                }
                ?>
               </select>
```

Mas eu tenho uma segunda pesquisa depois. Assim eu vou reaproveitar o v_patr que foi adicionado em w_a para pegar o elemento 1 do array.

```
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Seri" style="width:300"> 
            <?
                for($i=0;$i<=$w_indice;$i++)
                {   

                    //print('<option value="'.$i.'">'._[$i].'</option>'."\n");
                }
                ?>
                </select>
```

Mas eu não sei como pegar os elemento do w_a que foi criado em um JS dentro do php e atribuir ele ao: `print('<option value="'.$i.'">'.w_a[$i].'</option>'."\n");`

Answer (score 1):

O transporte da variável de uma linguagem para outra deve ser feita sobre uma nova requisição. Não só vai te incomodar tentar trafegar essa informação sobre as duas linguagens, como este é o jeito errado de fazer.

Para não reinventar a roda, sugiro você fazer a leitura [desta minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15028/popup-com-ajax-e-jquery/15081#15081) que dá um resumo sobre requisições `$.ajax` – que é a solução para os seus problemas.